# Force tesseract-ocr to recognize a single character?

Tags: python, tesseract

[image]

```
    api = tesseract.TessBaseAPI()
    api.SetOutputName("output")

    api.Init(".","eng",tesseract.OEM_DEFAULT)
    api.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789")
    api.SetVariable("tessedit_pageseg_mode", "7")

    pixImage = tesseract.pixRead('img.jpg')

    api.SetImage(pixImage)

    outText = api.GetUTF8Text()
    answer = outText.replace("\n", "").replace(" ", "")

    print answer
```

Above image, which is '1',  is recognized as '47' by tesseract which is already set to `api.SetVariable("tessedit_pageseg_mode", "7")`. What should I do to force it to recognize a single character from an image?

**P.S.: python 2.7.3 + tesseract 3.0.2**

Comment: python 2.7.3 + tesseract 3.0.2

Comment: I guess your pageseg_mode should be `10` (which stands for SINGLE_CHAR)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44619077/pytesseract-ocr-multiple-config-options for the source of the pageseg_mode values