# Get orientation pytesseract Python3

Tags: python, tesseract, python-tesseract

I want to get the orientation of a scanned document. I saw this post [Pytesseract OCR multiple config options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44619077/pytesseract-ocr-multiple-config-options) and I tried to use `--psm 0` to get the orientation.

```
target = pytesseract.image_to_string(text, lang='eng', boxes=False, \
config='--psm 0 tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
```

But I get an error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/folders/jy/np7p4twj4bx_k396hyc_bnxw0000gn/T/tess_dzgtpadd_out.txt'
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found another way to get the orientation using pytesseract:

```
print(pytesseract.image_to_osd(Image.open(file_name)))
```

This is the output:

```
Page number: 0
Orientation in degrees: 270
Rotate: 90
Orientation confidence: 21.27
Script: Latin
Script confidence: 4.14
```

Comment: It can detect script or font? What if the document contains different font?

Comment: This is a good solution, but found that it's not very accurate. In a small experiment I did on 9 rotated (right, left, down) PNG document pages, it detected the rotation correctly on only 6.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of writing **regex** to get the output from a string , pass the parameter `Output.DICT` to get the result as a `dict`

```py
from pytesseract import Output

im = cv2.imread(str(imPath), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
newdata=pytesseract.image_to_osd(im, output_type=Output.DICT)
```

The sample output looks as follows: Use the dict keys to access the values

```
{
    'page_num': 0,
    'orientation': 90,
    'rotate': 270,
    'orientation_conf': 1.2,
    'script': 'Latin',
    'script_conf': 1.11
}
```

Answer (score 3):

@lads has already mentioned the method whic can find orientation.
I have just used re to get by how much degree do we need to rotate the image.

```
imPath='path_to_image'
im = cv2.imread(str(imPath), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
newdata=pytesseract.image_to_osd(im)
re.search('(?<=Rotate: )\d+', newdata).group(0)
```