# Tesseract OCR on binary image

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I have a binary image like this,

[image]

I want to extract the numbers in the image using tesseract ocr in Python. I used `pytesseract` like this on the image,

```
txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
```

But I am not getting any good results.

What can I do in pre-processing or augmentation that can help tesseract do better.?

I tried to localize the text from the image using `East Text Detector` but it was not able to recognize the text.

How to proceed with this in python.?

Answer (score 2):

I think the page-segmentation-mode is an important factor here.

Since we are trying to read column values, we could use `--psm 4` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44619077/pytesseract-ocr-multiple-config-options))

```py
import cv2
import pytesseract

img = cv2.imread("k7bqx.jpg")
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(gry, config="--psm 4")
```

We want to get the text starts with `#`

```py
txt = sorted([t[:2] for t in txt if "#" in t])
```

Result:

```py
['#3', '#7', '#9', '#€']
```

But we miss 4, 5, we could apply `adaptive-thresholding`:

[image]

Result:

```py
['#3', '#4', '#5', '#7', '#9', '#€']
```

Unfortunately, `#2` and `#6` are not recognized.

Code:

---

```py
import cv2
import pytesseract

img = cv2.imread("k7bqx.jpg")
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thr = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gry, 252, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,
                            cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, blockSize=131, C=100)
bnt = cv2.bitwise_not(thr)
txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(bnt, config="--psm 4")
txt = txt.strip().split("\n")
txt = sorted([t[:2] for t in txt if "#" in t])
print(txt)
```