# How to read punctuation characters like '/', '_' and '\' from an image

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, python-tesseract

I want my program to read `/`, `_`, and `\` from an image but sometimes it reads `/` as `I` and `/_\` as `A`. I am using the pytesseract library to do this.
Is there a way to specifically read characters like `/_` and `\`?

Comment: Please make sure to understand you should always try to produce a minimal reproducible example. More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pytesseract.image_to_string`](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/) to read text from an image. Depending on your image, you may want to perform preprocessing before throwing it into Pytesseract. This can be a combination of thresholding, blurring, or smoothing techniques using [morphological operations](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html). Using this example image,

[image]

Here's the result printed to the console

[image]

We use the `--psm 6` config flag since we want to treat the image as a single uniform block of text. Here's some additional [configuration flags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44619077/pytesseract-ocr-multiple-config-options) that could be useful

```
import cv2
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"

image = cv2.imread('1.png',0)
data = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang='eng',config='--psm 6')
print('Result:', data)
```