# Bad character recognition with Pytesseract OCR for images with table structure

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, detection, python-tesseract

I use a code to locate text boxes and create a rectangle around them. This allows me to rebuild the grid around the table structure in the image.

However, even if the text box detection works very well, if I try to define the characters present in each rectangle, pytesseract does not identify them well and does not allow to find the original text.

Here is my Python code :

```
    import os
    import cv2
    import imutils
    import argparse
    import numpy as np
    import pytesseract

    # This only works if there's only one table on a page
    # Important parameters:
    #  - morph_size
    #  - min_text_height_limit
    #  - max_text_height_limit
    #  - cell_threshold
    #  - min_columns


    def pre_process_image(img, save_in_file, morph_size=(8, 8)):

        # get rid of the color
        pre = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        def img_estim(img, threshold=127):
            is_dark = np.mean(img) < threshold
            return True if is_dark else False

        # Negative
        if img_estim(pre):
            print("non")
            pre = cv2.bitwise_not(pre)

        # Contrast & Brightness control
        contrast = 2.0 #0 to 3
        brightness = 0  #0 to 100

        for y in range(pre.shape[0]):
            for x in range(pre.shape[1]):
                pre[y,x] = np.clip(contrast*pre[y,x] + brightness, 0, 255)

        # Otsu threshold
        pre = cv2.threshold(pre, 250, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

        # dilate the text to make it solid spot
        cpy = pre.copy()
        struct = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, morph_size)
        cpy = cv2.dilate(~cpy, struct, anchor=(-1, -1), iterations=1)
        pre = ~cpy

        if save_in_file is not None:
            cv2.imwrite(save_in_file, pre)
        return pre

    def find_text_boxes(pre, min_text_height_limit=15, max_text_height_limit=40):
        # Looking for the text spots contours
        # OpenCV 3
        # img, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(pre, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        # OpenCV 4

        contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(pre, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

        # Getting the texts bounding boxes based on the text size assumptions
        boxes = []
        for contour in contours:
            box = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
            h = box[3]

            if min_text_height_limit < h < max_text_height_limit:
                boxes.append(box)

        return boxes


    def find_table_in_boxes(boxes, cell_threshold=10, min_columns=2):
        rows = {}
        cols = {}

        # Clustering the bounding boxes by their positions
        for box in boxes:
            (x, y, w, h) = box
            col_key = x // cell_threshold
            row_key = y // cell_threshold
            cols[row_key] = [box] if col_key not in cols else cols[col_key] + [box]
            rows[row_key] = [box] if row_key not in rows else rows[row_key] + [box]

        # Filtering out the clusters having less than 2 cols
        table_cells = list(filter(lambda r: len(r) >= min_columns, rows.values()))
        # Sorting the row cells by x coord
        table_cells = [list(sorted(tb)) for tb in table_cells]
        # Sorting rows by the y coord
        table_cells = list(sorted(table_cells, key=lambda r: r[0][1]))

        return table_cells


    def build_lines(table_cells):
        if table_cells is None or len(table_cells) <= 0:
            return [], []

        max_last_col_width_row = max(table_cells, key=lambda b: b[-1][2])
        max_x = max_last_col_width_row[-1][0] + max_last_col_width_row[-1][2]

        max_last_row_height_box = max(table_cells[-1], key=lambda b: b[3])
        max_y = max_last_row_height_box[1] + max_last_row_height_box[3]

        hor_lines = []
        ver_lines = []

        for box in table_cells:
            x = box[0][0]
            y = box[0][1]
            hor_lines.append((x, y, max_x, y))

        for box in table_cells[0]:
            x = box[0]
            y = box[1]
            ver_lines.append((x, y, x, max_y))

        (x, y, w, h) = table_cells[0][-1]
        ver_lines.append((max_x, y, max_x, max_y))
        (x, y, w, h) = table_cells[0][0]
        hor_lines.append((x, max_y, max_x, max_y))

        return hor_lines, ver_lines


    if __name__ == "__main__":

        ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True,
            help="path to input image to be OCR'd")
            # ap.add_argument("-east", "--east", type=str,
            # help="path to input EAST text detector")

        args = vars(ap.parse_args())


        in_file = os.path.join("images", args["image"])
        pre_file = os.path.join("images", "pre.png")
        out_file = os.path.join("images", "out.png")

        img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(in_file))
        top, bottom, left, right = [25]*4
        img = cv2.copyMakeBorder(img, top, bottom, left, right, cv2.BORDER_REPLICATE)   
        orig = img.copy()

        pre_processed = pre_process_image(img, pre_file)
        text_boxes = find_text_boxes(pre_processed)
        cells = find_table_in_boxes(text_boxes)
        hor_lines, ver_lines = build_lines(cells)

        # (H, W) = img.shape[:2]
        # net = cv2.dnn.readNet(args["east"])
        # blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img, 1.0, (W, H),(123.68, 116.78, 103.94), swapRB=True, crop=False)
        # net.setInput(blob)

        # Visualize the result
        vis = img.copy()
        results = []

        for box in text_boxes:
            (x, y, w, h) = box

            startX = x -2
            startY = y -2
            endX = x + w
            endY = y + h 

            cv2.rectangle(vis, (startX, startY), (endX, endY), (0, 255, 0), 1)

            roi=orig[startX:endX,startY:endY]

            config = ("-l eng --psm 6")

            pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

            text = pytesseract.image_to_string(roi,config=config )


            results.append(((startX, startY, (endX), (endY)), text))


        results = sorted(results, key=lambda r:r[0][1])

        output = orig.copy()

        for ((startX, startY, endX, endY), text) in results:

            print("{}\n".format(text))
            text = "".join([c if ord(c) < 128 else "" for c in text]).strip()

            cv2.rectangle(output, (startX, startY), (endX, endY),(0, 0, 255), 1)
            cv2.putText(output, text, (startX, startY - 20),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 0, 255), 3)

        # for line in hor_lines:
            # [x1, y1, x2, y2] = line
            # cv2.line(vis, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 0, 255), 1)

        # for line in ver_lines:
            # [x1, y1, x2, y2] = line
            # cv2.line(vis, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 0, 255), 1)

        cv2.imwrite(out_file, vis)

        cv2.imshow("Text Detection", output)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Initial image :
[Initial image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2z3Z.jpg)
Preprocessed image with detection of text outlines to define the dimensions of rectangles :
[Preprocessed image with detection of text outlines to define the dimensions of rectangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDr4M.png)
Final image :
[Final image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuPXk.png)
Résultat obtenu par OCR :

"

a
ra
at

12

1
"

Thank you in advance for your help, hope my description is clear enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When performing OCR, it is extrememly important to preprocess the image to get the **foreground text in black with the background in white**. In addition, enlarging the image can help improve the detection results. I've also found that adding a slight Gaussian blur improves accuracy before throwing it into Pytesseract. Here's the results with `--psm 6` to treat the image as a single block of text. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44619077/pytesseract-ocr-multiple-config-options) for more configuration options.

---

Preprocessed enlarged, thresholded, and slightly blurred image

[image]

Results from Pytesseract OCR

```
Series Type Scan Range CTDIvol DLP Phantom
(mm) (mGy) — (mGy-cm) cm
1 Scout - - - -
1 Scout - - - -
2 Axial = 113.554-1272.929 11.22 269.35 Body 32
Total Exam DLP: = 269.35
1/1
```

Code

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
import imutils

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"

image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
image = imutils.resize(image, width=700)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
thresh = cv2.GaussianBlur(thresh, (3,3), 0)
data = pytesseract.image_to_string(thresh, lang='eng', config='--psm 6')
print(data)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imwrite('thresh.png', thresh)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! It was more a problem of coordinates sent to "roi". But it helped me however.

Comment: `foreground text in black with the background in white` this was the key for me, since there was as well a tiny black border cause of my `rectangleBorder`. Thank you