# How to extract text or numbers from images using python

Tags: python, image, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I want to extract text (mainly numbers) from images like this

[image]

I tried this code

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
img = Image.open('1.jpg')
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang='eng')
print(text)
```

but all i get is this 
(hE PPAR)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When performing OCR, it is important to preprocess the image so the **desired text to detect is in black with the background in white**. To do this, here's a simple approach using OpenCV to Otsu's threshold the image which will result in a binary image. Here's the image after preprocessing:

[image]

We use the `--psm 6` configuration setting to treat the image as a uniform block of text. Here's other [configuration options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44619077/pytesseract-ocr-multiple-config-options) you can try. Result from Pytesseract

> 01153521976

Code

```
import cv2
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"

image = cv2.imread('1.png', 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(image, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

data = pytesseract.image_to_string(thresh, lang='eng',config='--psm 6')
print(data)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.waitKey()
```