# How to read digits from an image with PyTesseract OCR?

Tags: python, image, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm trying to get PyTesseract OCR to read digits from this simple and well cropped Image, but for some reason it's just not able to do this.

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract as p

def obtain_balance(a):
    im = Image.open(a)
    width,height = im.size
    a = 300*5 - 120
    # print(width,height)
    left = 155+a
    top = 5
    right = 360+a 
    bottom = 120
    m1 = im.crop((left, top, right, bottom)) 
    text = p.image_to_string(m1,lang='eng',config='--psm 13 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789').split()
    print(text)
    m1.show()
    return text

obtain_balance('cur.jpg')
```

[image: Image I'm trying to read]

Output :

```
[]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When performing OCR, it is important to prepossess the image so that **the desired foreground text is in black with the background in white**. To do this, we can use OpenCV to Otsu's threshold the image and obtain a binary image. We then apply a slight Gaussian blur to smooth the image before throwing it into Pytesseract. We use `--psm 6` config to treat the image as a single uniform block of text. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44619077/pytesseract-ocr-multiple-config-options) for more configuration options.

---

Here's the preprocessed image and the result from Pytesseract

[image]

```
PRACTICE ACCOUNT
$9,047.26~ i
```

Code

```
import cv2
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"

image = cv2.imread('1.png', 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(image, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
thresh = cv2.GaussianBlur(thresh, (3,3), 0)
data = pytesseract.image_to_string(thresh, lang='eng',config='--psm 6')
print(data)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: + read https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/ImproveQuality