# How to extract text from the highlighted text from an image

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, opencv3.0, python-tesseract

I have a code that highlights the user's name from an image, I want to extract text i.e users name from that image. Below is the code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
import easyocr
from pylab import rcParams
from IPython.display import Image
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 8, 16
reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'])
output = reader.readtext('MP-SAMPLE1.jpg')
cord = output[-106][0]
x_min, y_min = [int(min(idx)) for idx in zip(*cord)]
x_max, y_max = [int(max(idx)) for idx in zip(*cord)]

image = cv2.imread('MP-SAMPLE1.jpg')
cv2.rectangle(image,(x_min,y_min),(x_max,y_max),(0,0,255),2)
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
```

I have set coordinates according to my image, you can adjust it according to yours, I need to extract the text which is highlighted under the rectangular box.
I am new in this field please ignore any mistake I would have done.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If possible, could you please share the `MP-SAMPLE1.jpg` or whatever image you are working with us?

Comment: I have added images in the question, please check

Comment: I've looked at your problem, but couldn't solve it. The best result I get is `GRAMONAN GROVER` most probably this is because I don't have indian pytesseract data.

Comment: were you able to extract it in text?...if yes can you please share the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my partial-solution for the problem.

Since you are beginner, let me give you an advice, always start with pre-processing.

Pre-processing will help you to remove the unwanted-artifacts.

For instance you can do `thresholding`: [Thresholding-result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poshX.png)

or `median` filtering: [Median-filter result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNinI.png)

I used `thresholding`, then you can use `pytesseract` library. The library contains a lot of [configuration options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44619077/pytesseract-ocr-multiple-config-options).

Also for non-english languages, you can follow this [tutorial](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2020/08/03/tesseract-ocr-for-non-english-languages/).

So, you want the text next to the `FATHERS HUSBANDS`. Therefore we could do

- 1. Convert image to the text.

     - ```py
       text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(f_name), lang='eng')
       ```
- 2. From the text, find the equivalent of `FATHERS HUSBANDS`

     - ```py
       for line in text.split('\n'):
           if "FATHERS HUSBANDS" in line:
               name = line.split('.')[1].split(',')[0]
               print(name)
       ```
     - Result:

       - ```py
         GRAMONAN GROVER
         ```

The last name is correct but first name is partially correct, it should be `BRAJMONAN`.

I wrote this answer, hoping you to gude to your solution. Good luck.

Code:

---

```py
import os
import cv2
import pytesseract

from PIL import Image

img = cv2.imread("FXSCh.jpg")
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold
gry = cv2.threshold(gry, 0, 255,
                    cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

f_name = "{}.png".format(os.getpid())
cv2.imwrite(f_name, gry)

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(f_name), lang='eng')

for line in text.split('\n'):
    if "FATHERS HUSBANDS" in line:
        name = line.split('.')[1].split(',')[0]
        print(name)

os.remove(f_name)

cv2.imshow("Image", img)
cv2.imshow("Output", gry)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: hello thank you for helping me out, the solution works well with a specific use case, but I  want to extract multiple details of a student & that too from multiple documents, now when I fed this solution a similar format mark sheet of another student it started giving me -1 as output & also when I try to extract students name the same way you extracted father's name, it gave me -1 output

Comment: any idea if there is a reliable way to detect text that has been highlighted physically in printed documents and digitally in PDFs?

Comment: @oldboy I'm not sure, but I think you may use [inRange thresholding](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.4/da/d97/tutorial_threshold_inRange.html).

Comment: awesome ill check it out. thanks