# Pytesseract can't read simple numbers

Tags: image, python-imaging-library, python-tesseract

I'm trying to read this number using pytesseract:

[image: image of the number 14]

and when I do it prints out `IL`:

```py
import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract'
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open("Number.jpg"))
print(text)
```

I've also tried converting the image to black or white:

[image: image of the number 14]

but this hasn't worked either. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pytesseract` works best and gives accurate output with black text on white background. Preprocessing is the main part to get accurate results. But in your case a simple inverse binary thresholding is more than enough to get the correct output as your image does not contain any noise at all. Adaptive thresholding should be used only in case of uneven lighting.

```
>>> image = cv2.imread("14.jpg",0)
>>> thresh = cv2.threshold(image,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
>>> data = pytesseract.image_to_string(thresh,config= '--psm 6 digits')
>>> data
'14'
```

I think tesseract's version does not cause any problem.

Tesseract version `tesseract v5.0.0-alpha.20200223`
pytesseract version `pytesseract Version: 0.3.4`

Answer (score 1):

I think you've missed to set `pytesseract`' page-segmentation-mode (`psm`) configuration to `7` which is treating image as a single text line. ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44619077/pytesseract-ocr-multiple-config-options))

I also applied thresholding, my result:

[image]

and when I set `psm` to 7

```py
txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(thr, config="--psm 7 digits")
print(txt)
```

Result:

```sh
14
```

Code:

---

```py
import cv2
import pytesseract

img = cv2.imread("d3njD.jpg")
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thr = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gry, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,
                            cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 4)
txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(thr, config="--psm 7 digits")
print(txt)
cv2.imshow("thr", thr)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Please note that, for other images, this solution may not work. You may need additional image processing methods, or you need to change the parameters.

- pytesseract version: `4.1.1`

Comment: Hmm I tried the exact same code as you and I'm now getting "ER" with the same exact code, now I'm wondering if it has something to do with my installation.

Comment: On the same image or a different image?

Comment: If you are getting `ER` on the same image could you please replace `txt = pytesseract` part in the code with `txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(thr, config="--psm 7 digits")`

Comment: So I tried doing that and this time I got no output (I believe) It printed <0x0c> into the console and that's it do you think it could be my pytesseract instillation?

Comment: Are you using the same code with mine? Or if you are using a different code, please post it to your question

Comment: And your pytesseract version is 4.1.1 right?

Comment: I did pytesseract.get_tesseract_version() and it said "LooseVersion ('5.0.0-alpha.20200328')"

Comment: If possible, could you please downgrade to 4.1.1 and see if my answer is working?