# why tesseract can't recognize the english words on this image?

Tags: tesseract, python-tesseract

I am using **tesseract 4.0** to recognize **english** words,but fail **only** on this image ,without any words been recognized,

any one can give a tip,thanks

```
    r=pytesseract.image_to_string('6.jpg', lang='eng')
    print(r)
```

[Fail image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YD90o.png)

**update:**

I try to OCR with online website

https://www.newocr.com/

and it works,but why?

how can I use tesseract to recognize it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `pytesseract` is not rotation-invariant. Therefore, you need to do additional pre-processing. [source](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/07/10/using-tesseract-ocr-python/)

- My first idea is to rotate the image with a small angle
- ```py
  img = imutils.rotate_bound(cv2.imread("YD90o.png"), 4)
  ```
- Result:

  - [image]
- Now if I apply an `adaptive-threshold`

  - [image]
- To read with `pytesseract` you need to set additional configuration:

  - ```py
    pytesseract.image_to_string(thr, lang="eng", config="--psm 6")
    ```
  - PSM (page-segmentation-mode) 6 is Assume a single uniform block of text. [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44619077/pytesseract-ocr-multiple-config-options)
- Result:

  - You want to get the last sentence of the image.
  - ```py
    txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(thr, lang="eng", config="--psm 6")
    txt = txt.replace('\f', '').split('\n')
    print(txt[len(txt)-2])
    ```
  - Result:
  - ```sh
    Continue Setub ie Gene
    ```

The website might use deep-learning method to detect the words in the image. But when I use newocr.com the result is:

```py
oy Eee a
setuP me -
continve ae
```

Comment: Ahx,thanks very much for your help
I will have a try according to your suggestion