# Python Extract number from simple Image

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, python-tesseract

I have the following image

[image]

```
lower = np.array([175, 125, 45], dtype="uint8")
upper = np.array([255, 255, 255], dtype="uint8")

mask = cv2.inRange(image, lower, upper)
img = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask)

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(img)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image]

now if I try to transform into grayscale like this:

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
```

I get that:

[image]

And I would like to extract the number on it.

The suggestion:

```
gray = 255 - gray
emp = np.full_like(gray, 255)
emp -= gray
emp[emp==0] = 255
emp[emp<100] = 0
gauss = cv2.GaussianBlur(emp, (3,3), 1)
gauss[gauss<220] = 0
plt.imshow(gauss)
```

gives the image:

[image]

Then using pytesseract on any of the images:

```
data = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config='outputbase digits')
```

gives:

```
'\x0c'
```

Another suggested solution is:

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
thr = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]
txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(thr)
plt.imshow(thr)
```

[image]

And this gives

```
'\x0c'
```

Not very satisfying... Anyone has a better solution please?

Thanks!

Comment: Add img = PIL.ImageOps.invert(img) before OCR

Comment: I tried: img = Image.fromarray(img), img = ImageOps.invert(img), data = pytesseract.image_to_string(img), yields the same result...

Comment: @NicolasRey you are doing the whole process of image processing, then you are passing the **raw** image before processing to the `pytesseract` : `data = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config='outputbase digits')` replace `img` by `gauss`!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a two step solution

---

- 1. Apply [thresholding](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html)
- 2. Set [psm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44619077/pytesseract-ocr-multiple-config-options) mode to 7.

When you apply thresholding to the image:

[image]

Thresholding is a simplest method of displaying the features of the image.

Now from the output image, when we read:

```py
txt = image_to_string(thr, config="--psm 7")
print(txt)
```

Result will be:

```sh
| 1,625 |
```

Now why do we set page-segmentation-mode (`psm`) mode to the 7?

Well, treating image as a single text line will give the accurate result.

But we have to modify the result. Since the current result is `| 1,625 |`

We should remove the `|`

```py
print("".join([t for t in txt if t != '|']))
```

Result:

```sh
1,625
```

Code:

---

```py
import cv2
from pytesseract import image_to_string

img = cv2.imread("LZ3vi.png")
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thr = cv2.threshold(gry, 0, 255,
                    cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]
txt = image_to_string(thr, config="--psm 7")
print("".join([t for t in txt if t != '|']).strip())
```

Update

---

> how do you get this clean black and white image from my original image?

Using 3-steps

- 1. Reading the image using `opencv`'s `imread` function

  - ```py
    img = cv2.imread("LZ3vi.png")
    ```
  - Now we read the image in `BGR` fashion. (Not `RGB`)
- 2. Convert the image to the graysclae

  - ```py
    gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ```
  - Result will be:

    - [image]
- 3. Apply threshold

  - ```py
    thr = cv2.threshold(gry, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]
    ```
  - Result will be:

    - [image]

Now if you are wondering about thresholding. Read the [simple-threhsolding](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html)

> All my filters, grayscale... get weird colored images

The reason is, when you are displaying the image using pyplot, you need to set color-map (`cmap`) to gray

```py
plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
```

You can read the other types [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html)

Comment: @AlexAlex print(txt.strip('| ')) output is `1,625 |`

Comment: strip ('|<space>')

Comment: Looks very nice, but how do you get this clean black and white image from my original image? All my filters, grayscale... get weird colored images

Comment: @NicolasRey I've updated my answer by including the answers to your questions. Please read `Update` part.

Answer (score 1):

Two issues blocked the `pytessract` from detecting your number:

1. The white rectangle around the number(Inverting and filling is the solution).
2. The Noise in the numbers shape(Gaussian Smoothing dealt with that)

The solution that [AlexAlex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13226440/alex-alex) has proposed will work perfectly if it was followed by a **Gaussian filter**:

> output: 1,625

```py
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
import cv2

BGR = cv2.imread('11.png')
RGB = cv2.cvtColor(BGR, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

lower = np.array([175, 125, 45], dtype="uint8")
upper = np.array([255, 255, 255], dtype="uint8")

mask = cv2.inRange(RGB, lower, upper)
img = cv2.bitwise_and(RGB, RGB, mask=mask)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

gray = 255 - gray
emp = np.full_like(gray, 255)
emp -= gray

emp[emp==0] = 255
emp[emp<100] = 0

gauss = cv2.GaussianBlur(emp, (3,3), 1)
gauss[gauss<220] = 0

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(gauss, config='outputbase digits')

print(text)
```

Comment: @NicolasRey because you didn't provide the original image before, just the grayscale image! you can check the update now.

Comment: I don't get why but I still do not manage to get your result even with the update. Do you get the same colored images I get after every filter? I have updated my result

Comment: @NicolasRey I'm using this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOT6f.png) that you have provided as an input with this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65834400), if you are using different image or you are using your own code I'm not sure what the result will be!