# tesseract fails at simple number detection

Tags: ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I want to perform **OCR** on images like this one:

[image: 6x6 matrix with numerical values]

It is a table with numerical data with colons as decimal separators.
It is not noisy, contrast is good, black text on white background.
As an additional preprocessing step, in order to get around issues with the frame borders, I cut out every cell, **binarize** it, pad it with a white border (to prevent edge issues) and pass only that single cell image to `tesseract`.
I also looked at the individual cell images to make sure the cutting process works as expected and does not produce artifacts. These are two examples of the input images for `tesseract`:

[image: Single cell from above table. Content: 1,7]

[image: Single cell from above table. Content: 57]

**Unfortunately, `tesseract` is unable to parse these consistently. I have found no configuration where all 36 values are recognized correctly.**

There exist a couple similar questions here on SO and the usual answer is a suggestion for a specific combination of the `--oem` and `--psm` parameters. So I wrote a python script with pytesseract that loops over all combinations of `--oem` from 0 to 3 and all values of `--psm` from 0 to 13 as well als `lang=eng` and `lang=deu`. I ignored the combinations that throw errors.

**Example 1:** With `--psm 13 --oem 3` the above "1,7" image is misidentified as "4,7", but the "57" image is correctly recognized as "57".

**Example 2:** With `--psm 6 --oem 3` the above "1,7" image is correctly recognized as "1,7", but the "57" image is misidentified as "o/".

**Any suggestions what else might be helpful in improving the output quality of tesseract here?**

My tesseract version:

```
tesseract v4.0.0.20190314
 leptonica-1.78.0
  libgif 5.1.4 : libjpeg 8d (libjpeg-turbo 1.5.3) : libpng 1.6.34 : libtiff 4.0.9 : zlib 1.2.11 : libwebp 0.6.1 : libopenjp2 2.2.0
 Found AVX2
 Found AVX
 Found SSE
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution

- 1. Divide the image into the 5-different row
- 2. Apply division-normalization to each row
- 3. Set psm to 6 [(Assume a single uniform block of text.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44619077/pytesseract-ocr-multiple-config-options)
- 4. Read

---

From the original image, we can see there are 5 different rows.

Each iteration, we will take a row, apply normalization and read.

We need to understand how to set image indexes carefully.

```py
import cv2
from pytesseract import image_to_string

img = cv2.imread("0VXIY.jpg")
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
(h, w) = gry.shape[:2]

start_index = 0
end_index = int(h/5)
```

---

**Question** Why do we declare start and end indexes?

We want to read a single row in each iteration. Lets see in an example:

The current image height and width are 645 and 1597 pixels.

Divide the images based on indexes:

| start-index | end-index |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 129 |
| 129 | 258 (129 + 129) |
| 258 | 387 (258 + 129) |
| 387 | 516 (387 + 129) |

Lets see whether the images are readable?

| start-index | end-index | image |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 129 | [image] |
| 129 | 258 | [image] |
| 258 | 387 | [image] |
| 387 | 516 | [image] |

Nope, they are not suitable for reading, maybe a little adjustment might help us. Like:

| start-index | end-index | image |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 129 - 20 | [image] |
| 109 | 218 | [image] |
| 218 | 327 | [image] |
| 327 | 436 | [image] |
| 436 | 545 | [image] |
| 545 | 654 | [image] |

Now they are suitable for reading.

---

When we apply the division-normalization to each row:

| start-index | end-index | image |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 109 | [image] |
| 109 | 218 | [image] |
| 218 | 327 | [image] |
| 327 | 436 | [image] |
| 436 | 545 | [image] |
| 545 | 654 | [image] |

Now when we read:

```
1,7 | 57 | 71 | 59 | .70 | 65

| 57 | 1,5 | 71 | 59 | 70 | 65

| 71 | 59 | 1,3 | 57 | 70 | 60

| 71 | 59 | 56 | 1,3 | 70 | 60

| 72 | 66 | 71 | 59 | 1,2 | 56

| 72 | 66 | 71 | 59 | 56 | 4,3
```

Code:

```py
import cv2
from pytesseract import image_to_string

img = cv2.imread("0VXIY.jpg")
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
(h, w) = gry.shape[:2]
# print(img.shape[:2])
start_index = 0
end_index = int(h/5) - 20

for i in range(0, 6):
    # print("{}->{}".format(start_index, end_index))
    gry_crp = gry[start_index:end_index, 0:w]
    blr = cv2.GaussianBlur(gry_crp, (145, 145), 0)
    div = cv2.divide(gry_crp, blr, scale=192)
    txt = image_to_string(div, config="--psm 6")
    print(txt)
    start_index = end_index
    end_index = start_index + int(h/5) - 20
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you explain why you think processing the table by rows (instead of by cells, like me) is beneficial? And what is the reasoning behind the "blur and divide" step? Anyway, your solution still is not better than what I got as there are two wrong cells: "70" -> ".70" from the first row and "1,3"->"4,3". The first mistake can be fixed by filtering the ".", so that is a minor issue, but the second mistake is harder to detect. Honestly, I am surprised that tesseract fails at such a simple and well-shaped input.

Comment: Result by reading cell by cell is same as reading row by row. Therefore I preferred reading row-by-row (less-expensive compared to cell-by-cell). Yes you are right about ".70->70" and `1.3->4.3`. I found a solution to make ".70->70" and "1.3->4.3", but this time other digits were misinterpreted.