# Recognize carattere with opencv and tesseract (java)

Tags: opencv, tesseract, threshold

I'm trying to detect text in the picture
[image]

using code:

```java
MatOfByte mob=new MatOfByte();

Imgcodecs.imencode(".png", src, mob);

byte bb[]=mob.toArray();

BufferedImage bi=ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bb));

String text = tesseract.doOCR(bi);
```

But Tesseract find `6,52.` It seems a clean image and I don't understand how `ocr` can fail.

I'm using `eng` language:
`tesseract.setLanguage("eng");`

> opencv ver 4.51
>
> tess4j-3.4.8

What's wrong in the image?

Answer (score 0):

I have a two step solution

---

- 1. Apply [adaptive-threshold](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html)
- 2. Set psm mode to [6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44619077/pytesseract-ocr-multiple-config-options)

---

When you apply `adaptive-threshold` to the image:

[image]

Now when you read the image:

```
€1,52
```

Code:

---

```py
import cv2
from pytesseract import image_to_string

img = cv2.imread("s6lVY.png")
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thr = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gry, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 21, 21)
txt = image_to_string(thr, config="--psm 6")
print(txt)
```

If you can't find the desired solution using pytesseract, you need to apply image-processing.