# Pytesseract does not detect me numbers

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, text-processing, python-tesseract, text-recognition

I am making a simple program to detect numbers in an image with python and pytesseract, but the case is that it always returns me ♀, I am analyzing an image like this:

[my image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3QRw.png)

and my code to read the numbers is the following:

```
import pytesseract
from pytesseract import (
    Output,
    TesseractError,
    TesseractNotFoundError,
    TSVNotSupported,
    get_tesseract_version,
    image_to_boxes,
    image_to_data,
    image_to_osd,
    image_to_pdf_or_hocr,
    image_to_string,
    run_and_get_output
)

def analizar_resultado(path): 
    image = cv2.imread(path, 1)
    
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, config = 'digits')
    print('texto detectado:', text)
```

but I can't make it work for me, I have tried more images of this type with better quality and others, but I can't get any number back, how could I solve this? Thanks a lot

Comment: Want to improve Tesseract text recognition? Goggle for _tesseract improve recognition_

Comment: I want to detect only digits, but what do you mean with Google for tesseract?? Thanks

Comment: Search for __Tesseract improve recognition__

Comment: and do you now something more that i can try? other ocr or something like that? Thanks

Comment: Requesting libraries is off-topic on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a three-step solution

---

- 1. Get each digit separately
- 2. Apply threshold
- 3. Read the output

---

Part-1: Get each digit separately

- You can get each digit by using index variables. For instance:

  - ```py
    s_idx = 0  # start index
    e_idx = int(w/5) - 10  # end index
    ```
- First get height and width of the image then for each digit, increase the indexes

  - ```py
    for _ in range(0, 6):
        gry_crp = gry[0:h, s_idx:e_idx]
        s_idx = e_idx
        e_idx = s_idx + int(w/5) - 20
    ```
- Result

  - | 0 | 0 | 9 | 9 | 7 | 6 |
    | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
    | [image] | [image] | [image] | [image] | [image] | [image] |
- Part-2: Apply threshold

  - | 0 | 0 | 9 | 9 | 7 | 6 |
    | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
    | [image] | [image] | [image] | [image] | [image] | [image] |
- Part-3: Read

  - ```
    0.9976
    ```

Unfortunately the second-zero can't be recognized as digit due to artifacts.

If you can't read image, try with different `psm` [configurations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44619077/pytesseract-ocr-multiple-config-options)

Code:

---

```py
import cv2
from pytesseract import image_to_string

img = cv2.imread("A3QRw.png")
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
(h, w) = gry.shape[:2]
s_idx = 0  # start index
e_idx = int(w/5) - 10  # end index

result = []

for i, _ in enumerate(range(0, 6)):
    gry_crp = gry[0:h, s_idx:e_idx]
    (h_crp, w_crp) = gry_crp.shape[:2]
    gry_crp = cv2.resize(gry_crp, (w_crp*3, h_crp*3))
    thr = cv2.threshold(gry_crp, 0, 255,
                        cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
    txt = image_to_string(thr, config="--psm 6 digits")
    result.append(txt[0])
    s_idx = e_idx
    e_idx = s_idx + int(w/5) - 20
    cv2.imshow("thr", thr)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

print("".join([digit for digit in result]))
```

Comment: but why the e_index first is -10 and next is -20?

Comment: To align each separate image to the center.

Comment: There are 6 images, so I thought dividing the `width` into 5 separate labels will give me 6 images.

Comment: and why in the resize you multiply w*3 and h*3? why the 3

Comment: Resizing the image is beneficial for getting an accurate result. `3` is just a number for getting the desired result. You can use any other positive number

Comment: and if i have an image with low resolution, how can i use the threshold and see better the img??