# Pytesseract skips "1" but not "10" in the same file

Tags: python, image-processing, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am working with pytesseract and openCV to try to recognize a table of numbers.
I have been working heavyly on the image to resize, resample and treshold its colors to make it easier for pytesseract to read. Below is the image I managed to generate.

My problem is that everytime a single "1" comes up in a row, pytesseract isn't able to recognize it...

This is the image I am trying to read (once I have applied all the mentionned processings) :
[image: The table of numbers]

This is the relevant part of the code :

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

img = cv2.imread('test.jpg', 0)
data = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
```

And this is the output:

```
10

499
```

I also tried with `--psm 10` and `--psm 13` but the outputs are just gibberish like the following :

```
=
:x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply [inverse binary threshold](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html):

[image]

Set page-segmentation mode to [6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44619077/pytesseract-ocr-multiple-config-options)

```
1
10
499
```

Code:

```py
import cv2
from pytesseract import image_to_string

image = cv2.imread('uHLww.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]
text = image_to_string(thresh, config="--psm 6")
print(text)
```

Second solution:

---

You don't even have to apply thresholding, setting `psm` to 6 will give you the result.

```py
import cv2
from pytesseract import image_to_string

print(image_to_string(cv2.imread('uHLww.png'), config="--psm 6"))
```

Comment: Yeah psm 6 is doing good with this one, thats weird as I have already tested it before... Thanks