# tesseract doesnt recognize individual text segments after whitelisting

Tags: python, tesseract, python-tesseract

I have an image I want to extract text from using tesseract and python. I only want to recognize a certain set of characters so I use `tessedit_char_whitelist=1234567890CBDE` as a config. However now tesseract doesnt seem to recognize the gaps between the lines anymore. Is there some character I can add to the whitelist so it recognizes the text as individual text again?

Here is the image after the whitelist:

[image: after whitelist]

Here is the image before the whitelist:

[image: before WL]

Here is the code responsible for drawing the boxes and the recognizing the characters in case youre wondering:

```py
#configuring parameters for tesseract
# whitlist = "-c tessedit_char_whitelist=1234567890CBDE"
custom_config = r'--oem 3 --psm 6 ' 
# now feeding image to tesseract
details = pytesseract.image_to_data(threshold_img, output_type=Output.DICT, config=custom_config, lang='eng')
print(details.keys())

total_boxes = len(details['text'])
for sequence_number in range(total_boxes):
    # confidence above 30 %
    CONFIDENCE = 0
    if int(details['conf'][sequence_number]) >= CONFIDENCE:
        (x, y, w, h) = (details['left'][sequence_number], details['top'][sequence_number], details['width'][sequence_number],  details['height'][sequence_number])
        threshold_img = cv2.rectangle(threshold_img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
# display image
cv2.imshow('captured text', threshold_img)
cv2.imwrite("before.png", threshold_img)
# Maintain output window until user presses a key
cv2.waitKey(0)
# Destroying present windows on screen
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

EDIT:

Here is the original image I want to extract the text from with the goal to write it to a matrix:

[image: Original image]

The desired matrix would take the following form:

```py
content = [
    ["1C", "55", "55", "E9", "BD"],
    # ...
    ["1C", "1C", "55", "BD", "BD"]
]
```

Comment: Please provide original image (without boxes) and desired output

Comment: Okay, shure I will edit it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One Solution is:

---

- 1. Individually take each tuple and upsample by 2
- 2. Apply [threshold](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html)
- 3. Recognize by setting page-segmentation-mode to [6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44619077/pytesseract-ocr-multiple-config-options)

---

|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tuple | [image] | [image] | [image] | [image] | [image] |
| Threshold | [image] | [image] | [image] | [image] | [image] |
| Result | 1C | 55 | 55 | E9 | BO |
| Tuple | [image] | [image] | [image] | [image] | [image] |
| Threshold | [image] | [image] | [image] | [image] | [image] |
| Result | 1C | 1C | 55 | BO | 1C |
| Tuple | [image] | [image] | [image] | [image] | [image] |
| Threshold | [image] | [image] | [image] | [image] | [image] |
| Result | 1C | 55 | BO | 55 | IC |
| Tuple | [image] | [image] | [image] | [image] | [image] |
| Threshold | [image] | [image] | [image] | [image] | [image] |
| Result | 1C | BD | 50 | 1C | 1C |
| Tuple | [image] | [image] | [image] | [image] | [image] |
| Threshold | [image] | [image] | [image] | [image] | [image] |
| Result | 1C | 1C | 55 | BD | BD |

The idea is taking each tuple separately, upsampling it, and then applying inverse-binary-threshold. Tesseract misinterpreted few tuples due to the font. For instance, if you look at the character `D` which looks like `O`. If you want 100% accuracy, then I suggest you [train the tesseract](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/Training-Tesseract). Also, make sure you try with other [page-segmentation-modes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44619077/pytesseract-ocr-multiple-config-options)

Here is the array output:

```py
[['1C', '55', '55', 'E9', 'BO'], ['1C', '1C', '55', 'BO', '1C'], ['1C', '55', 'BO', '55', 'IC'], ['1C', 'BD', '50', '1C', '1C'], ['1C', '1C', '55', 'BD', 'BD']]
```

Code:

---

```py
import cv2
import pytesseract

img = cv2.imread("IVemF.png")
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
(h, w) = gry.shape[:2]
s_idx1 = 0  # start index1
e_idx1 = int(h/5)  # end index1
cfg = "--psm 6"
res = []

for _ in range(0, 5):
    s_idx2 = 0  # start index2
    e_idx2 = int(w / 5)  # end index2
    row = []
    for _ in range(0, 5):
        crp = gry[s_idx1:e_idx1, s_idx2:e_idx2]
        (h_crp, w_crp) = crp.shape[:2]
        crp = cv2.resize(crp, (w_crp*2, h_crp*2))
        thr = cv2.threshold(crp, 0, 255,
                            cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV |
                            cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
        txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(thr,
                                          config=cfg)
        txt = txt.replace("\n\x0c", "")
        row.append(txt.upper())
        print(txt.upper())
        s_idx2 = e_idx2
        e_idx2 = s_idx2 + int(w/5)
        cv2.imshow("thr", thr)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
    res.append(row)
    s_idx1 = e_idx1
    e_idx1 = s_idx1 + int(h/5)

print(res)
```

---

Comment: Thank you very much, works very well with a few obvious replacements

Comment: You're welcome. You are right, maybe you would like to train tesseract for the particular tuples.