# problem in displaying pasted content form persian pdf

Tags: python, pdf, text, unicode, utf-8

i have a pdf code in persian language but when i try to copy the contents , the contents will display as nonsense alphabets (except numbers)
example  : i copied some text from my pdf and paste it here  :
371960012100240806356111 => '371960012100240806356111'
number pasted right

---

but when i try to copy something like name
گلچین فر
it will  be pasted
£3⁄4ÉuÅ{

how can i fix this problem ? i want to extract the contents with python and it works but i cant display the names correctly !

the pdf sample file is here : https://ufile.io/qibejys1

thanks

Comment: Apparently your PDF does not contain the information required for text extraction. Ask the distributor of the PDF for a version that does.

Comment: If you provide a link to your problematic PDF, we could help you to investigate

Comment: @Kfcaio  i uploaded a sample file

Comment: As assumed above, the PDF does not contain the information required for text *extraction* (**ToUnicode** tables or self-explanatory **Encodings**), so that won't work. An alternative approach would be **optical recognition** of the text as proposed by @Kfcaio's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try the following steps:

1. Install Tesseract 4 or higher, check [official tutorial](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/Installation.html)
2. Get the [Persian-specific model](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/blob/master/fas.traineddata) and copy it to your local tessdata folder
3. Convert problematic PDF pages (split pages first, take a look at `pdftk` tool) to tiff (In ubuntu, use `convert` command)
4. Run something like `tesseract -l fas image.tiff text.txt`
5. Tweak your command with options, like [psm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44632770/6328506)

Comment: I think you mean the [Persian-specific model](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/blob/master/fas.traineddata).