# Using pytesseract to get text from an image

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, python-tesseract

I'm trying to use pytesseract to convert some images into text. The images are very basic and I tried using some preprocessing:

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.bitwise_not(gray)
gray = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
```

The original image looks like this:

[image: Original]

The resulting image looks like this:

[image: Processed]

I do this for a bunch of numbers with the same font in the same location here are the results:

[image: Results Python]

It still gives no text in the output. For a few of the images, it does, but not for all and the images look nearly identical.

Here is a snippet of the code I'm using:

```
def checkCurrentState():
    """image = pyautogui.screenshot()
    image = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(image), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    cv2.imwrite("screenshot.png", image)"""

    image = cv2.imread("screenshot.png")

    checkNumbers(image)



def checkNumbers(image):
    numbers = []
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray = cv2.bitwise_not(gray)
    gray = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]


    for i in storeLocations:
        cropped = gray[i[1]:i[1]+storeHeight, i[0]:i[0]+storeWidth]
        number = pytesseract.image_to_string(cropped)
        numbers.append(number)
        print(number)
        cv2.imshow("Screenshot", cropped)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: try `THRESH_BINARY_INV`. report the results.

Comment: For questions involving image processing, you should also supply the original image.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I tried that it gave the same number of correct results(see edits).

Comment: @bfris See edits

Comment: remove the `bitwise_not`. that's an error to use there. your data is grayscale at this point, not binary. a `bitwise_not` will **mangle** the values, not invert them. just remove it.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz It didn't chane anything

Answer (score 2):

To perform OCR on an image, its important to preprocess the image. The idea is to obtain a processed image where the text to extract is in black with the background in white. Here's a simple approach using OpenCV and Pytesseract OCR.

To do this, we convert to grayscale, apply a slight [Gaussian blur](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_filtering/py_filtering.html#gaussian-filtering), then [Otsu's threshold](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html#otsus-binarization) to obtain a binary image. From here, we can apply [morphological operations](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html) to remove noise. We perform text extraction using the `--psm 6` configuration option to assume a single uniform block of text. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44619077/pytesseract-ocr-multiple-config-options) for more options.

---

Here's a visualization of each step:

Input image

[image]

Convert to grayscale `->` Gaussian blur

[image]

Otsu's threshold `->` Morph open to remove noise

[image]

Result from Pytesseract OCR

```
1100
```

Code

```
import cv2
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"

# Grayscale, Gaussian blur, Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread('1.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3,3), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Morph open to remove noise
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3,3))
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=1)

# Perform text extraction
data = pytesseract.image_to_string(opening, lang='eng', config='--psm 6')
print(data)

cv2.imshow('blur', blur)
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('opening', opening)
cv2.waitKey()
```